# Can the Heston model be shown to reduce to the original Black Scholes model if appropriate parameters are chosen?

Tags: option-pricing, modeling, black-scholes, stochastic-volatility, heston

## Summary

For Heston model parameters that render the variance process constant, the solution should revert to plain Black-Scholes. Closed from solutions to the Heston model don't seem to do this, even though the dynamics clearly do. Can anyone see how to resolve this? I care because I'm getting incorrect results for four independent implementations spanning three completely different methods of approaching the problem, but *not* getting incorrect results for Monte Carlo pricing based on time evolution of the SDEs.

## Details

I am implementing some option pricers based on the Heston model and using different methods:

- Monte Carlo simulation
- The original closed-form solution presented in Heston 1993
- The Green's function as presented in [this very nice MSc thesis](http://eprints.maths.ox.ac.uk/718/1/Sensen_Lin_thesis.pdf)
- Fourier methods

Unfortunately what I am finding is that while the final three (semi-)analytical solutions agree with one another, they do not agree with the Monte Carlo simulation and my intuition about the problem.

Given the Heston dynamics:
$$
    dS_t = \mu S_t,dt + \sqrt{\nu_t} S_tdW^S_t,\\
    d\nu_t = \kappa(\theta - \nu_t)dt + \sigma \sqrt{\nu_t}dW^{\nu}_t,\\
    dW^S_t dW^{\nu}_t = \rho dt\\
$$
it is clear that if we simply choose our parameters for the variance process $\nu_t$ such that it remains constant ($d\nu_t = 0, \nu_t = \nu_0$), we should return to the plain Black-Scholes dynamics
$$
    dS_t = \mu S_tdt + \sqrt{\nu_0} S_tdW^S_t .
$$
From this we can derive the analytical solution in the usual way and up with the following
$$
    C(S,t) = \mathcal{N}(d_1)~S-\mathcal{N}(d_2)~K e^{-r \tau} \\
    d_1 = \frac{\ln(\frac{S}{K})+(r+\frac{\nu_0}{2})(\tau)}{\sqrt{\nu_0}\sqrt{\tau}} \\
    d_2 = \frac{\ln(\frac{S}{K})+(r-\frac{\nu_0}{2})(\tau)}{\sqrt{\nu_0}\sqrt{\tau}} = d_{1}-\sqrt{\nu_0}\sqrt{\tau}.
$$
This is all well and good and is the reason that I feel comfortable in claiming that my three different implementations of the semi-analytical Heston solution must be wrong, despite their accord with one another. Further, the Monte Carlo simulation of the model *does* give the same price as the Black-Scholes equation in this case.

Analogous to the Black-Scholes model, the solution of Heston model as given in the original paper is of the form
$$
    C(S,v,t) = S P_1 - K e^{-r(\tau)} P_2,
$$
where
$$
    P_j = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{\pi} \int^\infty_0 Re [ \frac{e^{-i \phi ln(K)} f_j(x,\nu,T,\phi)}{i \phi} ] d \phi, \\
    f_j = e^{C + D \nu + i \phi x}, \\
    C = r \phi i \tau + \frac{\kappa \theta}{\sigma^2} {(b_j - \rho \sigma \phi i + d)\tau - 2 \log [\frac{1-ge^{d \tau}}{1-g} ] }, \\
    D = \frac{b_j - \rho \sigma \phi i + d}{\sigma^2} [ \frac{1-e^{d \tau}}{1-ge^{d \tau}} ], \\
    g = \frac{b_j - \rho \sigma \phi i + d}{b_j - \rho \sigma \phi i - d}, \\
    d = \sqrt{(\rho \sigma \phi i - b_j)^2 - \sigma^2(2 u_j \phi i - \phi^2)}, \\
    b_1 = \kappa - \rho \sigma \; \; \; b_2 = \kappa, \\
    u_1 = \frac{1}{2} \; \; \; u_2 = - u_1.
$$
so it seems rather apparent that for cases where the Heston model is equivalent to Black-Scholes, we must have $P_1 = \mathcal{N}(d1)$ and $P_2 = \mathcal{N}(d2)$.

To demonstrate, let's take $ \theta = \nu_0, \sigma = 0 $, implying $\forall \nu_0, d\nu_t = 0$.

When just considering the Heston dynamics, these parameters work nicely and everything is well behaved. The semi-analytical solutions, however, are plagued with division-by-zero (ex. $g$) and can't be handled directly. So instead we simply want to take them in the limit as $\sigma \to 0$. This is where it gets tricky now, as we're left with some very complicated formulas and no apparent link to $\mathcal{N}(d_j)$. I tried Mathematica's rather powerful symbolic calculus capabilities, but it was unable to show equality.

Testing some other limiting cases, I've made the following observations:

- For $\nu_0 \to 0$, all methods converge on the correct price (Black Scholes).
- For low strikes, $K \to 0$, all methods converge on the correct price ($S_0$).

To me, this suggests that the problem is in $P_2$, but that's all I have so far.

What direction should I take next?

Comment: @vanguard2k, Am I missing something? How is $dv_t = 0$ maintained if $v_0$ is nonzero and $\sigma > 0$? Clearly if $v_0 = 0$ and $dv_t = 0$ we're just left with the forward price, but that violates the $>0$ restriction you mentioned, no?

Comment: Sorry i think i went over something here too quickly. I was actually thinking about your choice of parameter $\theta = v_0$ and $\sigma=0$ without having fully understood your question i think. My bad. Sorry again. It has been a long day for me already...

Comment: @vanguard2k No problem. Thanks for the effort to answer after a long day :)    Am I to understand then, that your first response doesn't apply at all?

Comment: Yes unfortunately my first response was nonsense. I obviously didn't read your question carefully enough the first time. I shall look into the Heston paper today and see if I can work something out.

Comment: Which fourier methods are you trying?  This sounds to me like a branch-cut problem, likely solved as in Jim Gatheral's book.

Comment: @vanguard2k, Any luck? I am going to try today to work it out as well.

Comment: @johntyree, Unfortunately no, not yet.

Comment: @BrianB  I think you are right. I have solved the issue of the models not giving consistent answers, which turned out to be due some inconsistencies in treatment of variance vs volatility in the inputs. I have not yet, however, shown analytically how Heston degenerates to BS. I'll look for that book. Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

To recover the Black-Scholes pricing equation, you should first express the standard normal cdf in terms of its characteristic function analogous to the Heston solution:
$$
N(x) = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{\pi} \int_0^{\infty} Re [\frac{e^{-i\phi x} f(\phi)}{i\phi}] d\phi
$$
where $f(\phi)$ is the characteristic function of the standard normal distribution:
$$
f(\phi) = e^{-\frac{1}{2}\phi^2}.
$$
Hence, the Black-Scholes formula becomes
$$
    C(S,t) = S P_1 - K e^{-r(\tau)} P_2,
$$
where
$$
    P_j = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{\pi} \int_0^{\infty} Re [\frac{e^{-i\phi d_j} f(\phi)}{i\phi}] d\phi \\
    f_j = e^{-\frac{1}{2}\phi^2}, \\
    d_1 = \frac{\ln(\frac{S}{K})+(r+\frac{\nu_0}{2})(\tau)}{\sqrt{\nu_0}\sqrt{\tau}} \\
    d_2 = \frac{\ln(\frac{S}{K})+(r-\frac{\nu_0}{2})(\tau)}{\sqrt{\nu_0}\sqrt{\tau}} = d_{1}-\sqrt{\nu_0}\sqrt{\tau}.
$$

The distribution in the Black-Scholes model is standardized whereas in the Heston model, it is not. It may be easier to first transform the $P_j$ terms so that they have a similar structure. With $x=\log(S)$, the $P_j$ terms can be rewritten as:
$$
    P_1 = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{\pi} \int_0^{\infty} Re [\frac{e^{-i\phi \log(K)} e^{i\phi x + i\phi r \tau } f_1(\phi)}{i\phi}] d\phi \\
    f_1 = e^{\frac{1}{2} i v_0\tau\phi -\frac{1}{2} v_0 \tau \phi^2}, \\
    P_2 = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{\pi} \int_0^{\infty} Re [\frac{e^{-i\phi \log(K)} e^{i\phi x + i\phi r \tau } f_2(\phi)}{i\phi}] d\phi \\
    f_2 = e^{-\frac{1}{2} i v_0\tau\phi -\frac{1}{2} v_0 \tau \phi^2}. \\
$$
In this form, you should be able to show that the Heston model converges to the Black-Scholes model as $\sigma \to 0$ when $\theta = v_0$ (although the details may be rather tedious to go through...). You may want to try equivalent formulations of the solution, other than Heston's original (e.g. the form in Gatheral: The Volatility Surface or Cont & Tankov: Financial modeling with Jump Processes), which avoid the division by zero problem a bit.